# Code review for performance enhancement perspective

Tags: java, performance, hex

I have following method that converts a hex string into a byte array. Although I can achieve the same using methods available in Apache's-commons-codec library, `DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary()` and by using `BigInteger`. But all I need is performance. Is there a way following piece of code can be further optimized in anyway?

```
public static byte[] decodeHexString(String hexString) {
    if (hexString.length() % 2 == 1) {
        hexString = "0" + hexString;
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hexString.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i += 2) {
        bytes[i / 2] = hexToByte(hexString.substring(i, i + 2));
    }
    return bytes;
}
private static byte hexToByte(String hexString) {
    int firstDigit = Character.digit(hexString.charAt(0), 16);
    int secondDigit = Character.digit(hexString.charAt(1), 16);
    return (byte) ((firstDigit << 4) + secondDigit);
}
```

Comment: You can achieve the same effect via classes and methods already in the JDK. There is no need to write your own code or use third-party libraries for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest performance hit will be the use of `substring`, and calling `"0" +`, I would also see if you can also remove the use of `Character.digit` and finally, you might be able to not create a `byte[]` each time. A further optimisation would be to not use `% 2` at the start or and `i / 2` inside your loop.

Something like this.

```
// assume the input is valid.
static int digit(char ch) {
    return ch < 'A' ? ch - '0' : (ch & 31) + 10;
}

public static byte[] decodeHexString(String hexString) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(hexString.length() + 1) / 2];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    if ((hexString.length() & 1) != 0) {
        bytes[i++] = (byte) digit(hexString.charAt(j++));
    }
    for (; j < hexString.length(); i++, j += 2)
        bytes[i] = (byte) ((digit(hexString.charAt(j)) << 4) + digit(hexString.charAt(j + 1)));

    return bytes;
}
```

to reuse the `byte[]` you would have to pass in an array to use, avoiding it's creation.

You could optimise this further by using reflection to grab the underlying array in String.